# CakePHP forms aliases

Tags: cakephp

I wanted to know is it possoble to give alias (name different to the one in mysql table) to forms view.

For example my users table looks like:

```
id | username | password | email | group_id | first_name | last_name | created | modified
1  | admin    | somepass | mail  | 3        | Name       | last      | date    | date
```

add ctp file looks like:

```
    
    Form->create('User'); ?>
        
            
        Form->input('username');
            echo $this->Form->input('password');
            echo $this->Form->input('email');
            echo $this->Form->input('group_id');
            echo $this->Form->input('first_name');
            echo $this->Form->input('last_name');
        ?>
        
    Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

What I would like to know is it possible to give each field an alias that would be displayed on a webpage.

For example:

```
echo $this->Form->input('username', alias 'Your username');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $this->Form->input('username',  array('label' => 'Your username'));
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements